# 2sxc What is the supported DNN version of 2scx. Does it supports DNN Evoq 9.6+?

Tags: upgrade, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We have a site under 9.4.4 but we need to upgrade to at least 9.6.1+ for Liquid Content On Premise Updates before december. How is the upgrade plan for 2sxc?
Regards,

Comment: We have had reliable updates of 2sxc to the latest versions on all versions of DNN 9.06.01 and higher. I think what is more important is, what version of 2sxc are you running now? If you are on 2sxc 10.09.01 or earlier, you might want to wait for Daniel to answer - or setup a clone with hosts-override and test which order to upgrade the modules and DNN in. Usually its getting modules to the latest version first, then DNN upgrades, but there has been a lot of changes in DNN regarding Telerik, Dependency Injection, etc. Backups first, clones are worth your time, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow :)

AFAIK everything should just work - we have many Evoq customers using 2sxc in all kinds of versions.